# Create parent/child relationship from static rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

By connection to a webservice, I receive a list of data. Each record in the list contains three category fields, which I save in a product table with the following column markup:

```
CategoryName    SubCategoryName    SubSubCategoryName
-----------------------------------------------------
Men             Clothing           Jeans
Women           Jewelry            Bracelets
Women           Clothing           Hoodies
Men             Clothing           Hoodies
```

ProductTable: CategoryName | SubCategoryName | SubSubCategoryName

What I want to do, is to extract the categories from the product table and save them to a table with parent/child relationship.

```
Id     ParentId    CategoryName         
-------------------------------
1      NULL        Men
2      1           Clothing
3      2           Jeans
4      NULL        Women
5      4           Jewelry
6      5           Bracelets
7      4           Clothing
8      7           Hoodies
9      2           Hoodies
```

What SQL query can I use to perform this action?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Right, sorry: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: You have Men\Clothing\Jeans twice now? And please update the results also ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new table

```
create table NewCategories (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1)  primary key,
  ParentID int null,
  Name nvarchar(max)
)
```

Now, Insert all rows into the new table (this will assign the ID's)

```
insert into NewCategories (Name) 
select distinct CategoryName
from OldCategories

insert into NewCategories (Name) 
select distinct SubCategoryName 
from OldCategories

insert into NewCategories (Name) 
select distinct SubSubCategoryName
from OldCategories
```

Update the `NewCategories` table, setting the ParentID column, once for the `SubCategoryName`, and once for the `SubSubCategoryName`:

```
update nc2
set ParentID = nc1.ID
from NewCategories nc1
   inner join OldCategories oc on oc.CategoryName = nc1.Name
   inner join NewCategories nc2 on oc.SubCategoryName = nc2.Name

update nc2
set ParentID = nc1.ID
from NewCategories nc1
   inner join OldCategories oc on oc.SubCategoryName = nc1.Name
   inner join NewCategories nc2 on oc.SubSubCategoryName = nc2.Name
```

This assumes that there are no `*CategoryName` duplicates in the original table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93109/1)

---

For duplicates, you can do (slightly more complex)

```
--insert all categories
insert into NewCategories (Name) 
select distinct CategoryName
from OldCategories


--only categories in the "new" table now
insert into NewCategories (ParentID, Name)
select distinct n.ID, o.SubCategoryName 
from OldCategories o
  inner join NewCategories n on o.CategoryName = n.Name

--now subcategories are items with non-null parents, 
-- so we need a double join
insert into NewCategories (ParentID, Name)
select distinct n1.ID, o.SubSubCategoryName 
from OldCategories o
  inner join NewCategories n1 on o.SubCategoryName = n1.Name
  inner join NewCategories n2 on o.CategoryName = n2.Name and n2.ID=n1.ParentID
```

Here is a [new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a12e6), modified to handle duplicates

Comment: It is a very bold assumption that there are no duplicate names. Even on this simple example, it is very likely to have 'Clothing' subcategory under both 'Men' and 'Women' http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd097/1

Comment: Yeah, that's why I made it explicit, and waiting on OP to confirm. The initial example did not have such a case.

Comment: There are duplicate category names inside the product table, yes. Edited the initial post. Your fiddle works great, except for the duplicate categories. Could you post the change to also save those correctly.

Comment: You could try to just change an order of operation a bit. Insert main categories first. Then while inserting first subcategories join on already inserted main categories and get the parentid right there in the process. Repeat for subsubcategories, this time using both parent and grandparent to join.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic: tnx for the suggestions